# How to create document library for a new file type for use with inline and external editor?

Tags: document-library, document-template, sharepoint-foundation

I'm rather new to SharePoint, so apologies if this is too basic!

I need to create a Document Library in Foundation 2010 for storing [G-Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code) (.nc) files. I want to have the new and edit functionality launch the user's local G-Code editor if available or a rich-text in-browser editor if not (.NC files are just text files, AFAIK).

I've found a lot of information that calls for the utilization of Document Templates, but very little guidance on how to create one and I'm at a loss as to how to best create a G-Code document library that fits what I'm trying to do. Pointers and suggestions are very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! Interesting one also!

I would start by reading this [article on how to create a DocumentTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms868275) and see if it fits your needs.  That would make your .nc file to open in the right application.  The only problem is that I don't think you can poll the client computer to see if the required application is installed.  Microsoft does it by creating an ActiveX that does the check.

For the in-browser editing software, you will need to build some CustomAction that would allow the user an option like "Edit in the browser" in the Edit Control Block (ECB).  That custom action would lead to a custom Application Page that would be the browser editor.  By passing the ItemId and the ListId in the URL, you will be able to get the item and to display in a custom editor that you would build.  You can find some of those editors [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors).

Enjoy !

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I stopped when I got to the instructions about adding a DLL as there weren't any clues as to how to do that.