# Client Side (inline IDE) editor/app for editing (.js , .json, .css, .html) files in a Document Library

Tags: json, html-editor, spfx-webparts

We more and more store data as .json files in a Document Library.
Instead of (re)writing our configuration front-end, I would like users to edit the bare .json files.
(*and while we're at it, all related .js, .css and .html files in the DocLib*)

**Question: Is there an App or Client-Side code for editing/creating files in a Document Library?**

I am thinking a REST interface on top of a Document Library with the TinyMCE library or similar.

Oldskool solutions involve installing software or opening a DocLib with Explorer and using a locally installed editor:

- (2010) [How to create document library for a new file type for use with inline and external editor?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7627/how-to-create-document-library-for-a-new-file-type-for-use-with-inline-and-exter)
- (2012) [Open txt files in document library in an editor (notepad)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33128/open-txt-files-in-document-library-in-an-editor-notepad)

## Update #1

I am not after a DEV experience,
I am looking for a 100% Client Side solution for (end)users to edit HTML5 files **in the Browser**

Comment: Answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/206907/how-can-use-the-microsoft-monaco-editor-which-in-offie365-they-say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was answered:

Use the Built in (SPOinline) Monaco Editor:

Answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/206907/how-can-use-the-microsoft-monaco-editor-which-in-offie365-they-say

## Update: referenced post was deleted

> **Right now its only available in the "Modern lists and libraries experience"**

### This is not correct,

**The editor IS available in Office365 for ANY document**

All you have to do is get the URL right

- Open a .txt file from a Modern Library Experience
- Investigate the URL

It takes 3 parameters

```
    https://[SITE]/[LIBARY]/Forms/AllItems.aspx
    ?id=[SITE]%2F[LIBARY]%2F[FILENAME]
    &parent=%2F[RELATIVEPATH+LIBRARY]
    &p=5
```

*disclaimer: there could be some typos above*

**With some trial and error you will be able to open any .HTML or .JS from a Classic Library**

You then write a CSR script to rewrite the URLs in a Classic Library,
and it is one click, just like in the Modern Experiences

## Update

Gautam reports it doesn't work for him.

I have used this at least since october 2016 on multiple Tenants, do not know what could be wrong... as I said.. it takes some trial and error to get the URL 100% right

## Update (*because Mr. Allrood asked so kindly in the comments*)

The CSR script

```
"MonacoEdit": {
    View: function (ctx, fieldSchema, item) {
        eval(atob("dmFyIGZpbGVyZWYgPSBpdGVtLkZpbGVSZWY7dmFyIGZpbGVwYXRoID0gZmlsZXJlZi5zcGxpdCgnLycpOw=="));
        eval(atob("dmFyIGZpbGVuYW1lID0gZmlsZXBhdGgucG9wKCk7dmFyIHBhcmVudCA9IGZpbGVwYXRoLmpvaW4oJy8nKTs="));
        var uri = location.origin + parent + '/Forms/AllItems.aspx' + '?';
        uri += '&id=' + fileref + '&parent=' + parent + '&p=5';
        return '<a href="' + encodeURI(uri) + '" target=_blank><b>Edit</b></a>';
    }
}
```

Will display an Edit link **for an existing 'MonacoEdit' (*doesn't matter what type*) column**

[image]

Sorry for the encrypted JavaScript code, was just in the news them Russians hackers have been at it again (not that I think the Americans are clean)
Since I presume Mr Allrood is russian I couldn't resist some Friday programmers humor.

If you don't trust this `eval` code just paste this in your F12 console:

```
atob("dmFyIGZpbGVyZWYgPSBpdGVtLkZpbGVSZWY7dmFyIGZpbGVwYXRoID0gZmlsZXJlZi5zcGxpdCgnLycpOw==")
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a gulp task for this, called [gulp-spsync](https://github.com/wictorwilen/gulp-spsync), and then I can edit the assets in any editor I want and it will sync to any SharePoint destination.

Comment: Built or sync is no problem. I am looking for a 100% front-end experience

Comment: Got it. AFAIK there's very few tools that do that, of course you can always use the classic approach with opening with WebDAV/Explorer. Then you can also build your own editor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/create-file-handler-extensions

Comment: I have mapped networkshares, fine for one tenant connections, a pain for multiple tenants (although they are persistant for some time becauyse Windows stores the credentials) The FileHandler still requires back-end dev. It should just be a as simple as TinyMCE using the CRUD REST API on documents in a DocLib. Cisar does it with js files in the Style Library.. but the UI only picks up JSLinks